# Why is this map() method here used in this code and how can JSX markup used inside the curlies? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I 'm building an image carousel using React, to practice it.

Problem is: I don't understand why this bit of code

```
    {/* // why is this here  */}
        {images.map(
          (image, index) =>
            current === index && (
              <div key={image} className="slide">
                <img src={image} alt="images" />
              </div>
            )
        )}
```

is inserted, more specifically why it's using a map method here at all.
Also, how can the JSX be used inside the curly braces (like .  From my understanding, you have to exit out of the braces to return to JSX. You use curly braces to use javascript.Here if never returns back to JSX and yet it uses `<div>`?

https://react.dev/learn/javascript-in-jsx-with-curly-braces

and why is `key` property created here? What's the purpose of it?

The example code is below and here's the same copy in sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-field-xp5sol?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js:881-888

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const images = [
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3836292/pexels-photo-3836292.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2792157/pexels-photo-2792157.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1166209/pexels-photo-1166209.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1661179/pexels-photo-1661179.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500"
];

export default function App() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

  function nextSlide() {
    setCurrent(current === images.length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
  }

  function prevSlide() {
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? images.length - 1 : current - 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Project 1: Carousel</h2>
      <div className="slider">
        <div className="left-arrow" onClick={prevSlide}>
          ⬅
        </div>
        <div className="right-arrow" onClick={nextSlide}>
          ⮕
        </div>

    {/* // why is this here  */}
        {images.map(
          (image, index) =>
            current === index && (
              <div key={image} className="slide">
                <img src={image} alt="images" />
              </div>
            )
        )}


      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But I was able to implement carousel with this, without map :

```
//Component
import { useState } from "react";
const images = [
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3836292/pexels-photo-3836292.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2792157/pexels-photo-2792157.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1166209/pexels-photo-1166209.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1661179/pexels-photo-1661179.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
];

export default function Carousel() {
  // use State to make react remember the varaible..?
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  //  you just define here
  function nextSlide() {
    // go back to index 0 after the last slide
    if (index === images.length - 1) {
      setIndex(0);
    } else setIndex(index + 1);
  }
  function prevSlide() {
    // if index is 0, go to the last lslide
    if (index === 0) {
      setIndex(images.length - 1);
    } else setIndex(index - 1);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={prevSlide}>previous</button>
      <button onClick={nextSlide}> next </button>
      <img src={images[index]} />
    </>
  );
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

According to the docs map method returns an array populated with elements that the callback function has called on. But why is that needed when you already have all you need in the original array? In this case, array is filled with urls, which is just what we need.

As for the JSX markup, I searched through the react docs again and I still can't figure out how the above code is possible, because you should exit out of the curlies to be able to use that .

Appreciate any help, let me know if anything is not clear and needs more explanation.

Comment: In your example, `.map()` is used to *find* a single element whose `index` is equal to `current`, as there are no two elements of the same array with the same index. Since the index we need is already there, stored in `current`, this can be replaced with `<div ...><img src={images[current]}></div>`.

Comment: `map` used in a JSX block is used to convert an array of data to an array of valid JSX elements, either HTML blocks or other Components. In the example you've given it is only returning a single element from the array, which is indeed unneccessary. [`key`](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key) is used to uniquely identify blocks of HTML allowing React to track what needs to be re-rendered

Comment: @pilchard thanks for the answer. So the map method is kind of unnecessary here. Any idea why one might choose to use it when they don't need it?

Comment: Well, I can't think of any reasons for such a choice. Simply remove it and ask that person if possible.